# Autofs with multiple path parameters

Tags: autofs

`autofs` has a `auto.master` configuration file that assignes maps files to paths, and in these maps files we can define how to mount subdirectories of the paths from `auto.master`. These subdirectories can be explicit or we can use `*` which becomes a wildcard(which we can refer to in the mount options using `&`). Additionally, if we make a maps file executable it will receive that subdirectory as it's first(and only) argument, and be expected to write the mount definition to stdout.

Now, my problem is that I need 2 wildcards/arguments. I want that if someone tries to access `/mymount/<foo>/<bar>`, where `<foo>` and `<bar>` can be any legal file names, it will create a mountpoint on `/mymount/<foo>/<bar>` to a target that depends on both `<foo>` and `<bar>`. My problem is that the I can only use one wildcard(which is `<foo>`), and with the executable maps file approach the argument I get is just `<foo>` and I `autofs` expects me to return mount options that will be mounted on `/mymount/<foo>`.

Is what I want even possible with `autofs`? I can easily find docs for a single parameter, but nothing about using multiple parameters...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you might be able to do is have them combined into one, say foo+bar, so it will be one argument, then have the executable map script split on the + and use the results as the two path parts to use.  But as far as I know autofs (and really any mounting) only takes one argument for the path to mount on, not two.